# Neo4j Traverser - Just get an item with specific type

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

Starting at any given Node I want to run the traverser till it hits a node which has "contentpage" as type (all nodes have a type-property).

I've tried it with the following traverser

```
{
    "order":"depth first",
    "uniqueness" : "node global",
    "relationships":[
        {"type":"CONTAINS","direction":"in"},
        {"type":"HAS","direction":"in"}
    ],
    "prune evaluator":{"language":"javascript","body":"position.endNode().getProperty('type')!='contentpage';"},
    "max depth":10000000
}
```

But all I get is a HTTP-Error 500.
Any Ideas?

Edit: Here's a stack trace (I've trimmed it a bit because it was huge)

```
Problem accessing /db/data/node/782350/traverse/node. Reason:

    javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: type property not found for NodeImpl#782348. (<Unknown Source>#1) in <Unknown Source> at line number 1
Caused by:

org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.EvaluationException: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: type property not found for NodeImpl#782348. (<Unknown Source>#1) in <Unknown Source> at line number 1
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.EvaluatorFactory$CompiledScriptExecutor.eval(EvaluatorFactory.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.EvaluatorFactory$ScriptedPruneEvaluator.pruneAfter(EvaluatorFactory.java:241)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalDescriptionImpl$WrappedPruneEvaluator.evaluate(TraversalDescriptionImpl.java:239)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MultiEvaluator.evaluate(MultiEvaluator.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.initialize(TraversalBranchImpl.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.next(TraversalBranchImpl.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.StartNodeTraversalBranch.next(StartNodeTraversalBranch.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserImpl$TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserImpl.java:127)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserImpl$TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserImpl.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.traverse(DatabaseActions.java:922)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.traverse(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, it seems you should have

```
 "uniqueness" : "node global"
```

Generally, you can't send in nulls. Just don't set something if you want the default. Have a look here for more information: [Neo4j REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-traverse.html).

**Edit** for updated question:

So the exception says:

```
NotFoundException: type property not found for NodeImpl
```

which is caused by:

```
position.endNode().getProperty('type')
```

To avoid this, set a default value for the the property, for example:

```
getProperty('type','')
```

Comment: I removed the nulls and added the uniqueness but it still does not work.

Comment: Could you update the question with the current request? Does it still give you a HTTP 500?

Comment: Thank's for the help, now it works. Is there a documentation for the prune evaluator?

Comment: There's a little [in the rest api docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-traverse.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look at the data/log/*.log and data/messages.log file for possible stack-traces?

Thanks

Comment: I've got a stack trace now, see my original post.

Comment: Have you looked at the node with id # 782348 if that one really has a type property? The stacktrace says it doesn't.

Comment: It definitely has a type property.